# Component is not ready Cannot assign object to property

Tags: qt, qml, components, qtquickcontrols2, stackview

I have a c++ class that inherited from `QObject` with name `LoginManager` (that I registerd this with `qmlRegisterTypes`) in `main.qml` file

```
LoginManager{
    id: loginManager
}
```

now I want to add a `LoginPage.qml` file to a  `StackView`

```
sv.push("/pages/LoginPage.qml",{lManager:loginManager});
```

**LoginPage**

```
Page {
    id: root
    property LoginManager lManager

    Connections{
        target: lManager

        onMessageChanged: {
        }
        onLoginSuccessed: {
        }
    }
}
```

but I have and error when click button to add `LoginPage.qml` to `StackView`

> QmlComponent: Component is not ready
>   qrc:/main.qml:395:5: QML StackView: push: qrc:/pages/LoginPage.qml:16 Cannot assign object to property

I have done same work on another pages but I don't know why I got error just here?

**Edit**

when I comment the Connections ,the error will go!

Comment: LoginManager is a QQuickItem or a QObject?

Comment: @eyllanesc It is a c++ class that inherited from QObject

Comment: push requires an Item, which in C ++ is equivalent to QQuickItem, if LoginManager is unique I would recommend creating it in C ++ and using setContextProperty() to export it to QML and you can access that object in any part of your application.

Answer (score -2):

You used an **absolute** URL to point to your login page component. Try to make it **relative**:

```
sv.push("./pages/LoginPage.qml",{lManager:loginManager});
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Hm... this is strange. I reproduced your problem locally (in pure QML) and using the absolute path was what actually caused the `Component is not ready` message to be printed. Maybe you could try to change the property from `property LoginManager lManager` to be `property var lManager`; sometimes I had trouble with "typed" properties in the past as well, but I cannot say for sure if this will solve your issue...